# MEF 2 - Where is RegistrationBuilder

Tags: mef2

I am completely confused this evening.  I've read almost a dozen posts on how to use the RegistrationBuilder in MEF 2 to build the Composition Context.  However, there's no such class in the MEF 2 that I loaded down to build WinRT applications.  Can someone please give a quick road-map explaining why there's such differences between the on-line discussion surrounding MEF 2 and the actual classes that I'm working with in the latest copy of MEF 2?  Also, a URL for the help for this library would be very useful.

Comment: It appears that the analog is the 'ConventionBuilder' builder class.  It is a subset of the RegistrationBuilder and uses the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration.RegistrationBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.registration.registrationbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It looks like its not supported in WinRT.